# Prevent the Workspace default settings from overriding the manually entered User settings in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings, prettier, workspace

How could I use User settings inside VS Code if there are always Workspace settings?

I am working with a project directory. I am working using VS Code, but other team members use different IDEs to work with the directory. So, we are not allowed to add any IDE specific folders (e.g. the `.vscode` folder). That means in reality the project has no VS Code Workspace settings. But whenever I go to the Settings I still can see that Workspace tab.

I tried to update the `prettier.tabWidth` property in User to be `4`, while in Workspace it is `2` and still VS Code uses the value from Workspace even though there are no Workspace files and the value is merely default. And I can not change the Workspace settings, since then the Workspace settings file will get added to the project.

So, basically the default Workspace settings override the manually put User settings. That is depressing actually since it makes User settings useless.

E.g. is there any way for me to set the `prettier.tabWidth` to `4` without adding Workspace settings files to the project?

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you sure there is no `.vscode` folder in the workspace, what if you open the corresponding `settings.json` file (button top right)

Comment: @rioV8, yeah, I am very sure there is no `.vscode` folder. I checked in Windows file explorer and in VS Code explorer. Then I checked in version control that it gets created if I update the Workspace settings (I reverted it back afterwards). Also, I checked the `settings.json` for the User settings and it contains exactly what I need, but unfortunately the default Workspace settings override it. As I remember it was not like that before (I was working on the current project for half a year), so it must be due to update. But I asked the question just in case there is a solution.

Comment: if you are very sure that an update is the cause you can ask at the VSC repo (an issue), create a test workspace to be sure, you need to supply the detailed steps to recreate. What might work is delete the `state.vscdb` in the `<user>\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage` folder, find the right folder by inspecting `workspace.json`. I had very strange behavior sometimes. Deleting the `state.vscdb` and backup file solved the problem, the `state.vscdb` was very big.